# How do I run or quit a program at a certain time with Event Viewer?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, event-viewer

I'm using the program Tunebite to convert songs. I need to convert a lot of songs and then quit the program after all processing is complete. There's an option to shutdown after completion but not to just quit.

How would I do this? I have no idea how Event Viewer works with program hooks, but I'm assuming I have to figure out how to recognize that processing is complete.

Comment: Does the program you're using write an event to a log when processing is complete? If it does not, then I'm not sure how Event Viewer is relevant here.

Comment: @Crippledsmurf As far as I can tell, it only writes error and performance logs, not process logs. Can you recommend another approach to my problem then?